# How to add getline in c++?

Tags: c++, function, integer, program-entry-point, getline

I am looking to remove the space from the name part of my assignment which allows users to put any name with or without space in my product list. for example "TV stand", I assume getline function will help me with it but I couldn't add the getline function into my main. can anyone help me with it?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct product {
    char product_name;
    int no_of_purchase;
    int no_of_sales;
    double purchase_cost;
    double selling_price;
    double profit_loss;
    double percent_profit_loss;
    string product_sales;
};
bool Compare(product P1, product P2)
{
    return P1.percent_profit_loss > P2.percent_profit_loss;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the number of the product:";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "\n";
    product Products[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << "Enter the name of the product: ";
        cin >> Products[i].product_name;
        cout << "Enter the number of " << Products[i].product_name << " purchased: ";
        cin >> Products[i].no_of_purchase;
        cout << "Enter the number of " << Products[i].product_name << " sold: ";
        cin >> Products[i].no_of_sales;
```

Comment: Sidenote: you may want to read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: `product_name` is one character long.  Those are not very descriptive product names.

Comment: I got rid of the double spaced code to try to make it more readable however it is missing at least a few `}`

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. I guess you know [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). So, what happens when you use it?

Comment: Maybe the bug is: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) however the part of the code with getline() was not added to the question

Comment: I don't understand that why are you using `char` not `char array` or `string` to write product name

Comment: @AhmarAamir that is a good point. A `char` is a single character which won't make an interesting product name.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I don't understand your question but this might be helpful for you

I changed the `product_name` data type from `char` to `string` because the `char` data type is not making any sense

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct product {
    string product_name;
    int no_of_purchase;
    int no_of_sales;
    double purchase_cost;
    double selling_price;
    double profit_loss;
    double percent_profit_loss;
    string product_sales;
};
bool Compare(product P1, product P2)
{
    return P1.percent_profit_loss > P2.percent_profit_loss;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the number of the product:";
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "\n";
    product Products[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << "Enter the name of the product: ";
        getline(cin, Products[i].product_name);
        cout << "Enter the number of " << Products[i].product_name << " purchased: ";
        cin >> Products[i].no_of_purchase;
        cout << "Enter the number of " << Products[i].product_name << " sold: ";
        getline(cin, Products[i].no_of_sales);
        cin.ignore();
    }
    return 0;
}
```